# Angular 2 router.navigate

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to navigate to a route in Angular 2 with a mix of route and query parameters.

Here is an example route where the route is the last part of the path:

```
{ path: ':foo/:bar/:baz/page', component: AComponent }
```

Attempting to link using the array like so:

```
this.router.navigate(['foo-content', 'bar-contents', 'baz-content', 'page'], this.params.queryParams)
```

I'm not getting any errors and from what I can understand this should work.

The Angular 2 docs (at the moment) have the following as an example:

```
{ path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }

['/hero', hero.id] // { 15 }
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? I'm on router 3.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

If the first segment doesn't start with `/` it is a relative route. `router.navigate` needs a `relativeTo` parameter for relative navigation

Either you make the route absolute:

```
this.router.navigate(['/foo-content', 'bar-contents', 'baz-content', 'page'], this.params.queryParams)
```

or you pass `relativeTo`

```
this.router.navigate(['../foo-content', 'bar-contents', 'baz-content', 'page'], {queryParams: this.params.queryParams, relativeTo: this.currentActivatedRoute})
```

See also

- https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/c61d8195f3b63c3e03bf2a3c12ef2596796c741d/public/docs/_examples/router/ts/app/crisis-center/crisis-detail.component.1.ts#L108
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9476

Comment: Know this thread is old - but a couple of quick questions for my understanding:
1. In the 2nd case above shouldn't it be 
`this.router.navigate(**['foo**-content', 'bar-contents',....` 
(without the / at the beginning of first segment, since it is relative)
2. Apart from this.currentActivatedRoute what are the other possible values for relativeTo?

Comment: If you want it to be relative, then omit the leading `/`, I didn't intend that. Any route you want the path be relative to.

Comment: Thanks - but in your reply you have mentioned that if the first segment starts with a  /, then it is an absolute navigation. So why would the relativeTo be required?

Comment: Now I see what you mean. `relativeTo` makes only sense with a relative route. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 16):

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class ClassName {
  
  private router = ActivatedRoute;

    constructor(r: ActivatedRoute) {
        this.router =r;
    }

onSuccess() {
     this.router.navigate(['/user_invitation'],
         {queryParams: {email: loginEmail, code: userCode}});
}

}


Get this values:
---------------

ngOnInit() {
    this.route
        .queryParams
        .subscribe(params => {
            let code = params['code'];
            let userEmail = params['email'];
        });
}
```

Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/NavigationExtras-interface.html

Answer (score 2):

As simpler as

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor( private router:Router) {}

    return(){this.router.navigate(['/','input']);}
```

Here you will be redirecting to route input .
If you wish to go to particular path with relative to some path then.

```
return(){this.router.navigate(['/relative','input']);}
```

Here on return() is the method we will be triggered on a button click

<button (click)=return()>Home