# In @NgModule, how to open different component due to something like user type

Tags: angular, router

In @NgModule , how to open different component due to something like user type?

I have a NgModule , have two different pages, and I want to open different page due to the user type

```
@NgModule({
imports: [ SharedModule ,RouterModule.forChild([
{ path: 'edit', component: EditComponent },
{ path: 'view', component: ViewComponent }
])],

declarations: [
EditComponent, ViewComponent
],

})
export default class MainModule { 
constructor(private u:UserService){
   //------

   //------
} 
}
```

the environment is : RC5

Comment: What is "user type" and where does it come from? Do you want the user type to be reflected in in the browsers URL bar? You can just use `<div *ngIf="userType=='x'">x</div><div *ngIf="userType=='y'"`>y</div>`

Comment: thank you, like   if(u.type=='manager') navigate('edit'); else navigate('view');

Answer (score 0):

Inject the router and call `navigate(...)`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ SharedModule ,RouterModule.forChild([
    { path: 'edit', component: EditComponent },
    { path: 'view', component: ViewComponent },
  ])],
  declarations: [
    EditComponent, ViewComponent
  ],
})
export default class MainModule { 
  constructor(private u:UserService, router:Router, ){
    if(u.type=='manager') {
      router.navigate(['/edit']);
    } else {
      router.navigate(['/view']);
    }
  } 
}
```

See also [Angular 2 router.navigate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131293/angular-2-router-navigate)

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router.

Comment: How does your AppModule look like

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 if (this.user.userType === UserType.x1) {
  this.router.navigate(['/edit']); } 
else if (this.user.userType === UserType.x2) {
            this.router.navigate(['/view']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after testing:
when in lazy load mode,
  writting this code in ngModule can cause an infinite loop

```
constructor(private router:Router){
     console.log("MainModule 39");
     this.router.navigateByUrl("/tabs-demo/tab3");
}
```

when not in lazy load mode, 
   writting that code in ngModule can cause

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router
```

the answer is: 
writting that navigation code in the first component.

testing in RC5

thanks.