# Angular 6 - Trigger Browser "save login prompt"

Tags: angular, authentication, login-control, jquery-easyui

So, i already create small application (learning purpose) to manage some data. The problem is, browser doesn't prompt to save login account on login page since all the application is `single page app` and i want my browser to prompt save login account. I already found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382329/how-can-i-get-browser-to-prompt-to-save-password) that probably fits to me, but because i just learning this angular 6, i cant really relate them.
So here is my Code.

**login.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    loginForm : FormGroup;

     username = "";
     password = "";

    constructor(
            public global: GlobalService,
            public messagerService: MessagerService,
            private cookie: CookieService, //persistent
            private router: Router,
            private fb: FormBuilder
        ) {
              this.loginForm = fb.group({
                  username: ["asdsa", Validators.required],
                  password: ["adssa", Validators.required]
              });
           }

    login(){
        var helper = new JwtHelperService();
        if(this.username=='' || this.password=='')
            this.messagerService.alert({
                title: 'Error',
                icon: 'error',
                msg: 'Please fill the forms!'
            });
        else{
            this.global.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(
                data => {
                    if(data.success=='1'){
                        this.cookie.set('jwtObj', data.jwt, new Date().getSeconds() + 7200, '/');
                        this.global.loginCheck();
                    }
                    else if(data.success == '0'){
                        this.messagerService.alert({
                            title: 'Error',
                            icon: 'error',
                            msg: data.msg
                        });
                    }
                },
            );
        }
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    submitForm(value){
        console.log(value);
    }

}
```

**login.component.html**

```
<eui-panel [title]="'Login Panel'" [collapsible]="true" [bodyStyle]="{padding:'20px'}" style="height:320px;width:400px; margin:auto;margin-top: 25vh">
        <h2>RUC SSO LOGIN</h2>
        <form novalidate #formm [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(loginForm)">
            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <label [for]="t1" align="top">Username:</label>
                <eui-textbox #t1 formControlName="username" iconCls="icon-man" placeholder="username" style="width:100%"></eui-textbox>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <label [for]="t2" align="top">Password:</label>
                <eui-passwordbox #t2 formControlName="password" placeholder="password" style="width:100%"></eui-passwordbox>
            </div>
            <div>
                <eui-linkbutton (click)="submitForm(loginForm)">Login</eui-linkbutton>
            </div>
        </form>
</eui-panel>
```

How can i trigger browser prompt?

Comment: why this `(click)="submitForm(loginForm)"`in `eui-linkbutton`? you already submitting form.

Comment: no, i just copy paste from easyui(example page). i know it is redundant, but since it has same outcome, i leave as it. somehow i cant submit the form via click event, so i call a function

Comment: Try navigate to another URL after success.

Comment: then i can't really implement single page app with angular?

Comment: I mean navigate through [Router](https://angular.io/guide/router) to another component. Implement routing, then navigate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131293/angular-2-router-navigate

Comment: i already implement it on this.global.loginCheck();
it is my prev implementation but gives me same result

Comment: I'm afraid that this is browser behavior, I simply created login form and hit enter button from keyboard, save password prompts. I think you should use button rather than link.

Comment: can u give me the fiddle?ill try it, if it is work, u can add as answer

Answer (score 1):

Okay here's I created a simple example, tested on Firefox
[stackblitz app URL](https://angular-sy2z4d.stackblitz.io/)

and [stackblitz editor URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sy2z4d)

[image]

Edit: You are using easyui, that might be issue with easyui but save password prompts on form submit and navigating to other component.

Comment: Yeah that's might be problem in easyui but I never worked on it, did you try to remove linkbutton and add just simple html button? I worked on devextreme components, and I was also getting prompt.

Comment: yes, i replace the tags i mention earlier with standard html tags and it is work.

Comment: (edited first comment)
turns out browser didn't recognize <eui-textbox>, <eui-linkbutton> and <eui-linkbutton> tags since i'm using easyui, current work around is to use native tag input on login page. You can complete the answer by adding this information. thankyou for helping me sir..