# Get object parsed by HttpHeader in different angular component

Tags: angular, http

Basically I have a problem where, when I get the parameters from my `router`, it seems like they come, but in a bad format.

Everything down here is working, so I can see on the Output what I want.

```
   userLogin() {
        this.restApi.auth(this.userDetails).subscribe(dados => {
          let headers = new HttpHeaders().append("X-token",     JSON.stringify(dados));

          headers = headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

          console.log("Dados:", dados, "Headers: ", headers);

          this.router.navigate(["main-page"], { queryParams: headers });
        });
      } `
```

Now when I go to the other component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.router.routerState.root.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      console.log("Parametros no Main: ", params);
      this.getUser(params);
      console.log("User: ", this.user);
    });
 }
```

I can only see in my params something like this:

> {normalizedNames: "[object Map]", lazyUpdate: Array(2), headers:
>   "[object Map]",    lazyInit: "[object Object]"} headers: "[object
>   Map]" lazyInit: "[object Object]"    lazyUpdate: Array(2) 0: "[object
>   Object]" 1: "[object Object]" length: 2
>   **proto**: Array(0) normalizedNames: "[object Map]"
>   **proto**: Object

I know there are two objects o `lazyUpdate`, but they have that weird format.

What can I do to get these parameters correctly?

Comment: Why are you setting `queryParams` to a `HttpHeaders` object instance? This is not going to work. What query params do you expect `userLogin()` to set?

Comment: I want to get the "X-token" on the main-page, I was trying to put in main-page the header

Comment: I can't tell if you know what a query param is. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Can't I get the headers in the other component, by putting this as a query param?

Comment: something like the second awnser of this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131293/angular-2-router-navigate

Comment: try `{ queryParams: { token: JSON.stringify(dados) } }`