# How to back one or two path with new parameter in angular routing?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using angular 15.0 for my project. There are two shared paths in routing-module. for example:
The first path: is: **'../customer/:customerId/showInvoice/:invoiceId'**
And the second path is: **'../customer/:customerId/newInvoice/:customerId'**.
When we have followed the second path to the end, so that a new invoice is saved, so far, we have retrieved the invoice ID from the database and we have it. For example:
**../customer/3/newInvoice/3** and the retrieved invoiceId is 15. So, now we want to back one path with new parameter (i.e. we switch on the first path to show the new invoice which has created), i.e.
**../customer/3/showInvoice/15**.
Is this scenario possible? If so, what method can be used? Is it possible to use Angular LocalStrategy service? and how? I will be grateful if you provide a suitable solution. Best regards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38131293/angular-2-router-navigate does this anwswer your question?

Comment: Does the answer in the link you sent mean that the following statement works for my question? this.router.navigate(['../showInvoice', invoiceId]

Comment: Or this: this.route.navigate['../showInvoice', invoiceId, relativeTo: this.currentActivatedRoute]

Comment: Try `this.router.navigate(['customer', '3', 'showInvoice', invoiceId]);`
I have not tested this one. Of course you can pass the customer id as parameter as well like `invoiceId`.